# Could AJAX results be out of synch and cause a discrepancy in polled results?

Tags: php, ajax, settimeout

I am developing functionality similar to an auction, using jQuery, AJAX, PHP and mySQL.

Ajax accesses the server every second to get the most recent bid, and during this call we also get the remaining time from the server to keep all participants in sync.

I have two issues:

1) Occasionally the time remaining flickers back to the value of the previous time for a fraction of a second. Could this is to do with the asynchronous results getting out of sync?

Snippets of the relevant code:

```
function dotimer() {
    updateScreen();
    setTimeout('dotimer()',1000);
}

function updateScreen(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'getinfo.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { /* various params are passed to php */ },
        success : function(data){
            /* other info processed here...*/
            $("#countdowntimer").html(data.secondsremaining);           
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
    });
}
```

getinfo.php:

```
$return['secondsremaining'] = strtotime($end_time)-strtotime("now");
/* get other infor from database... */
echo json_encode($return);
```

(setTimeout and setInterval both had the same results.)

2) Is accessing the database every second excessive? I can't see an alternative to ensure information is up-to-date. Is there a better way to do this? 
The auction is for a relatively short period of time (30 min) and we do not expect any more than 10 participants.

Any advice/suggestions welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's exactly your problem. As the requests are asynchronous, you cannot control the order that they are executed. You have to synchronize your requests and avoid multiple requests ie you can only do a new request if there aren't pending requests, else you cannot control when the callback for each request is fired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @woozy. How do you suggest doing this? Will synchronising the requests not cause the page to wait for each request to complete before allowing the user to interact with it? We don't want to prevent the user placing a bid when the page is interacting with the server - they shouldn't be aware that is even happening.

Comment: Requests synchronization will not affect page interaction as they run in background. I would suggest you to try runnig new request on each request callback, instead of running it every second.

Comment: Sorry, I was told using SJAX would have that effect so I didn't even look at synchronous requests. What's the best way to do this - call the setTimeout in the success and error callback functions? It will also require a change in the logic of the process - As we were making calls per second anyway we chose to return the server time too. Now the timer will no longer count down each second so I'll need a separate countdown timer & will have to sync this with the server time as a js countdown is not accurate. It is crucial all participants are as in sync as possible.

Comment: In callback you would call updateScreen() not the setTimeout. And maybe you could use a separate handler for the timer. For example you could get the endTime in an unix timestamp from server and then use javascript to calculate the remaining time over that timestamp. And then have a separate handler to check the end time from server and updating on client side when necessary. Of course you should then include some veryfications on the stamps to avoid fraud.

Comment: I'll need a timeout in the callback, otherwise the ajax call will be accessing the server and database multiple times a second (a bit excessive)! I'd come across a similar way of syncing the time every 10 seconds with a separate handler like you suggested... I thought I'd came up with a way of doing the two calls in one but unfortunately I hadn't forseen this issue :) Looks like I might have to go with separate handlers after all. Thanks for your help!